# ggplot2 change colorbar label

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, colorbar

I want to plot a **matrix**. In order to clearly see the low values, code is like below.

```
p <- ggplot(data = melt(x))
p + geom_tile(aes(x=Var2,y=Var1,fill = value))
```

Now in order to see details, I prefer use square root scale. 
But if I change 
`fill = value` to fill = `sqrt(value)`
the colorbar range will change too(For example, original is c(0,100), now is c(0,10)).

What I want is to plot `sqrt(value)`but still use the colorbar of `value`

I checked `guide_colorbar()`but there is only argument about whether to show labels, no argument about how to set own labels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `trans` argument of of `scale_fill_gradient`:

```
p + 
    geom_tile(aes(x = Var2, y = Var1, fill = value)) + 
    scale_fill_gradient(trans = "sqrt")
```

Here's a sample plot, using the following data:

```
x <- matrix(1:16, 4, 4)
```

[image]

As you can see, `trans` transforms the data for both the plot and the colorbar, so your color scale will be root-transformed but you can identify colors to their original values.

Comment: Really thank you, the manul I used only provides trans in x and y axis. Never thought it can also be used in scale_fill_**, help me a lot, thanks again!